# Looping with twig

Tags: php, ruby, symfony, twig

How do I do this with twig?

```
    foreach($estimate_data AS $year => $month) {
        foreach ($month AS $monthNo => $estimates) {
          $chart_data .= "['". $year ."/".$monthNo."',"; 
          foreach (array(0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20) AS $est){
              $chart_data .= (isset($estimates[$est]) ? $estimates[$est] : 0) .",";
          }
          $chart_data .= "],\n";
        }
    }
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm struggling with the inner foreach and checking the existence of an element in the array:

```
      {% for year, month in chart_data %}
        {% for month_no, estimates in month %}
          ['{{year}}/{{month_no}}',
          {% for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20]  %}
            {% if estimates %}
            {{estimates[i]}} ,
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: what doesnt work or what error do you get ?

Comment: @mpm Key "2" for array with keys "0, 1, 3, 5, 8" does not exist in ApplicationDefaultBundle:Estimates:index.html.twig at line 17

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Untested!!..

```
{% for year, month in estimate_data %}
    {% for month_no, estimates in month %}
        {% set chart_data = chart_data ~ "['" ~ year ~ "/" ~ monthNo ~ "'," %} # concat the strings
        {% for est in [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20] %}
            {% set chart_data = chart_data ~ (defined estimates.est) ? estimates.est : 0 ~ ',' %} # if estimates.est is defined
        {% endfor %}
        {% set chart_data = chart_data ~ "],\n" %} # concat the final string.
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:**
I guess, if you try to concat using:

```
{% set variable ~= 'text' %}
```

This should work, but I don't even test this..

Comment: Thanks @victor, but I get this crazy error: An opened parenthesis is not properly closed. Unexpected token "name" of value "estimates" ("punctuation" expected with value ")") in ApplicationDefaultBundle:Estimates:index.html.twig at line 18

Comment: Sorry Man, try, (estimates.est is defined) ? estimates.est : 0 ... this work!!